# Facebook The authorization has been revoked. Reason: Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have problem when i login to facebook in my system to get my pages. The facebook api sent to my server response: The authorization has been revoked. Reason: Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token.
The fields I was set is

`String[] fields = {"name", "about", "category", "checkins", "likes{fan_count", "were_here_count}", "link", "talking_about_count", "id", "posts", "access_token", "app_id", "page_token", "picture{url}"};`

What is problem and how to i fix it? Before i can use it normally. I just had this problem recently

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your token has probably expired.

You can debug your token related issues on: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/%20access-tokens/debugging

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?
  input_token={input-token}&
  access_token={valid-access-token}
```

Running the above should return more info on your token.
This should give you an idea on how to proceed. You can generate new tokens on the facebook developer page.